# iPhone Can subview be transparent?

Tags: iphone, uiview, opacity

I have main view and i added subview to it. I set subview's background to be semi transparent, but subview is drawn in solid color. I even tried setting opaque to NO.

```
detailsView.opaque = NO;
detailsView.backgroundColor = UIColorMakeRGBA(0, 0, 100, 100);
```

I can make the vsubview to be transparent via alpha property (but all things on subview will also be transparent), but i really want just to set background color to be semi transparent.

Comment: Is `UIColorMakeRGBA ` a function that you have defined? If yes, can you post its code or confirm that it looks like the code in my answer?

Comment: Yes, it is user defined function, thou not by me... Problem was i thought alpha is also devided by 255.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `alpha` to desired value in `colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha method`

```
detailsView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0f 
                                              green:30/255.0f 
                                               blue:160/255.0f 
                                              alpha:0.5f];
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the `UIColorMakeRGBA` function, but it looks to me like you are creating a completely blue colour with alpha of 1, so it should not be transparent. Try setting the background colour line to be

```
detailsView.backgroundColor = UIColorMakeRGBA(0, 0, 100, 50);
```

Alternatively just use `[[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5f];`

Answer (score 1):

I assume `UIColorMakeRGBA` is a function that you have implemented. In that case, I am sure, it looks like this:

```
#define UIColorMakeRGBA(redValue, greenValue, blueValue, alphaValue) [UIColor colorWithRed:(redValue)/255.0f green:(greenValue)/255.0f blue:(blueValue)/255.0f alpha:(alphaValue)]
```

Notice that alpha is not divided by `255.0`, so you should use a value between `0.0` and `1.0` for that parameter and not `100`. If you use 100, you will end up with a color with alpha equal to `1.0`.

```
detailsView.backgroundColor = UIColorMakeRGBA(0, 0, 100, 0.5f);
```